# Crash: String Issues?

Tags: c++

I am creating a feature of my Crysis Wars server modification that accurately obtains the country of the player. This information is used to tailor the frontend of the server modification to the player (for example, if the player is German, show German language).

I have this code, which *should* work fine, but does not (edit this post if you want to fix the indents):

```
int GetFileForCountry(const char *ip)
{
    if (!ip)
    {
        CryLogAlways("[ThunderBolt 7] Internal Error: No IP was defined.");
        return false;
    }
    char myUrl[255];
    CryLogAlways("1");
    sprintf(myUrl,"http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=%s", (const char*)ip);
    CryLogAlways("2");
    CryLog("[ThunderBolt 7] Downloading file from source: %s", myUrl);
    CryLogAlways("3");
    const char *ch = gEnv->pConsole->GetCVar("sys_root")->GetString();
    CryLogAlways("4");
    const char *fLo = ("%sMods/Infinity/System/temp.txt",ch);
    CryLogAlways("5");
    std::wstring line;
    std::cout<<myUrl;
    CryLogAlways("6");
    getline(std::wcin,line);
    HRESULT hr;
    CryLogAlways("7");
    hr = URLDownloadToFile(NULL,(LPCSTR)line.c_str(),_T(fLo),0,NULL);
    CryLogAlways("8");
    return fLo;
}
```

The software has been crashing (reason behind the multiple CryLogAlways), and I have found that it's crashing on `CryLog("[ThunderBolt 7] Downloading file from source: %s", myUrl);`. I'm not sure if it's the declaration of `myUrl` that is going wrong, or just the string in the `CryLogAlways`. I have spoken to a mate of mine who is a C++ 'expert' and he does not know what is wrong.

I've also searched for various solutions (have gone through more than 5 complete replacements for this code), but none of them have worked. I've used this code before and it's worked fine.

It's not that urgent, but if you can point out the problem to me, please do :).

Comment: Are you sure that `ip` points to a readable, null-terminated string that is at most ~200 chars long? Validate that at runtime to make sure. Or hardcode a string literal for debugging purposes.

Comment: Why not use sting - i.e. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: `("%sMods/Infinity/System/temp.txt",ch);` O_o

Comment: `fLo[255]` are you sure it has the `255`th element?

Comment: So the `sys_root` CVar has 256 elements (minimum) ? interesting.

Comment: @usr The `ip` should be no more than 20 chars, but a bug in a DLL that I don't have the sourcecode to means that sometimes it returns the domain.
@BartoszKP It'll be up to around 100 chars, depending on the initial root of the system.
@WhozCraig It's 256 chars maximum. Where is this defined so I can change this?

Comment: @AlexanderStopher In the last line of your code you're accessing the `255`th element. Aren't you aware of that?

Comment: @BartoszKP I wasn't- I'll change this now. Thanks :).

Comment: Going backwards: `const char *fLo = ("%sMods/Infinity/System/temp.txt",ch);` this line probably doesn't behave as you've intended. You should at least use `sprintf` here. And the third thing: follow the advice from @usr: verify what's inside the `ip` string (simplest check - use `strlen`).

Comment: The function is supposed to return an `int` and you return `fLo` which is of type `char *`.

Comment: @BartoszKP Changed. It's the `CryLog("[ThunderBolt 7] Downloading file from source: %s", myUrl);` line which is giving the error, not the other lines.

Comment: Also, with `return (char *)fLo;`, I get `cannot convert from 'char *' to 'int'`; how to properly convert it?

Comment: Why do  you want to return `int` in the first place ?

Comment: @AlexanderStopher Yes I know, so I'll repeat once more: follow usr's advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that C++ was treating it as two different variables:

```
CryLog("[ThunderBolt 7] Downloading file from source: %s", myUrl);
```

The `CryLog` function only takes one argument and as such, had issues.
There are numerous ways to approach this, one of these ways is to:

```
CryLog(string("[ThunderBolt 7] Downloading file from source: ") + myUrl);
```